# Finding the Top 2 scores and returning the corresponding adjacent values from a row array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of values with scores and layer information in text format in adjacent cells. I want to find the highest score and return the adjacent cell with the text info and similalrly to find the second highest score with the adjacent cell info, note the top two have may have the same score but they should have different text values.

I have tried Index and match formulas.

```
=INDEX(Table2[@],MATCH(MAX(Table2[@]),Table2[@],0)+1)
```

Sample data layout

```
Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer   Score   Layer
7       River   6       Lake    7       Coastal 8       Canal   6       Lake    7       River   10      Reservoir   8   Canal   10      Estuary
```

Comment: Thanks a million Forward Ed, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer UPDATED to reflect data layout

Without using an array formula but using a formula that does array operations, you could use aggregate.  Its basically the same process as JvdV answer but uses different formula.

Cell references are based on the information in screenshot below, adjust them to suit your needs.

To get the highest scores,  AGGREGATE can be used to pull the specific values from a sorted list  using equations 14 or 15 which sort the  information in descending or ascending accordingly.  Same as the Large or Small function.  In this case the function looks like:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$5:$S$5,ROW(A1))
```

Place the formula above in cell C10 and copy down as needed.

Once you have the values you want to pulled from the list, you can use AGGREGATE again to grab their corresponding column numbers, and then dump those column numbers into an INDEX formula to pull the appropriate text values.  Remember you need to add +1 to the column number as the text you want is in the column to the right.  COUNTIF is used at the end to deal with duplicates.  The big question is if you had more than a 2 way tie for first, do you want the first two in the list to be displayed or the last two in the list to be displayed?  The difference will be whether 14 or 15 for the AGGREGATE function gets used.  In this example the first two in the list will be used. If you want the last two change the formula number in AGGREGATE.

```
=INDEX($5:$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$5:$S$5)/($B$5:$S$5=C10)+1,COUNTIF($C$10:C10,C10)))
```

Place the formula above in cell D10 and copy down as needed.

If you look at the formulas used by JvdV and this answer, they are basically the same.  The big difference is that JvdV formulas are ARRAY formula and require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to confirm the formula and just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is required for this formula.

In either case, within array operations, full column/row references should be avoided as they will lead to excessive calculations.  Note that for this answer the full row reference of $5:$5 was used outside the AGGREGATE function, but a defined range was used inside AGGREGATE ($B$5:$S$5)

[image: POC]

Comment: Always a pré not to use the brackets! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can I add a file or screen shot, I'm not that familiar with Stack Overflow?

Comment: @user1856146 yes you can.  how you do it may change depending on your reputation score.  Look at the icons at the top of your editing window for the question.  one will be for adding pictures.  If you rep is too low, then just add a link.  Usually someone will come along and convert your link to an embedded picture.  Pictures cannot be added to comments.  TEXT tables are preferred over screen screen shots.  Much easier for 100 people to copy and paste the data than it is for 100 people to re type your screen shot.

Comment: @user1856146  Also to accept an answer that you feel best answered your question click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it.  This is different from using the up and down arrows though both can be used.

Comment: Score Layer Score Layer  Score Layer
7 River 6 Lake  7 Coastal
8 Canal 6 Lake  7 River
10 Reservoir 8 Canal  10 Estuary

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice Forward Ed. The answers are great, however, my data is horizontal rather than vertical i.e. Score1, layer1, Score2, Layer2, Score 3, Layer3 etc see example in my previous comment! I'd appreciate any further advice!

Comment: @user1856146 extra info from comments should be put into your original question by editting it.  If I should decide to delete my answer, all the comments attached to it would disappear as well.  keeping that information in the question keeps it from being lost and makes it so people do not have to read through all the comments.  I added the sample data from your comments to your question, is that the correct layout?

Comment: @user1856146 Updated to answer to closer reflect your data

Comment: Thanks a million Forward Ed for your help, tea

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be a bit more trickier than you anticipated at first. Here are my steps:

Sample data:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LARGE(TestTable[ColumnA],ROW())
```

Formula in `D1`:

```
{=INDEX(TestTable[ColumnB],SMALL(IF(TestTable[ColumnA]=E1,ROW(TestTable[ColumnA])-ROW(A$1)),COUNTIF(E$1:E1,E1)))}
```

Drag down both formulas. Note last one is an array and needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I'm curious to know if there are any other more straightforward ways myself!

Comment: does the ROW(A$1) need to change if the table was not located starting in A1?  ie if the upper left coner of the table was G22?

Comment: @ForwardEd, in that case you'll use `ROW(G$22)` or `ROW(A$22)` indeed.